# Trigger Returning Unexpected Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a server-wide trigger that would prevent compression or partitioning being lost on any index that has it.  Right now, it's only in development. The trigger is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbtrg_PREVENT_COMPRESSED_PARTITION_LOSS_ON_INDEXES] ON ALL SERVER
AFTER DDL_EVENTS


AS


SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #t
    (
      ServerName sysname,
      DatabaseName sysname,
      TableName sysname,
      IndexName sysname,
      PartitionNumber INT,
      CompressionType NVARCHAR(60)
    );

DECLARE @dbName sysname;
DECLARE @dbCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET 
@dbCursor = CURSOR 
FOR SELECT name
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE source_database_id IS NULL 
        AND database_id > 4
        AND NAME <> 'AdventureWorks2008R2'
        AND is_read_only = 0
        AND state_desc = 'ONLINE'
    ORDER BY name;

OPEN @dbCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @dbCursor INTO @dbName;

WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
    BEGIN   

        SET @sql = 'USE [' + @dbName + ' ]
            INSERT INTO #t
            SELECT  @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName, 
                    DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName,
                    st.name AS TableName,   
                    si.name AS IndexName,
                    sp.partition_number AS PartitionNumber,
                    sp.data_compression_desc AS CompressionType
            FROM    sys.partitions SP WITH (NOLOCK)
                    LEFT JOIN sys.tables ST WITH (NOLOCK) ON st.object_id = sp.object_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes SI WITH (NOLOCK) ON sp.object_id = si.object_id 
                                    AND sp.index_id = si.index_id
                                    AND st.object_id = si.object_id
            WHERE st.type = ''U''
                    AND data_compression <> 0
            ORDER BY st.name, si.index_id, si.name, sp.partition_number';
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
        FETCH NEXT FROM @dbCursor INTO @dbName;
    END;

CLOSE @dbCursor;
DEALLOCATE @dbCursor;


DECLARE @xmlEventData XML = EVENTDATA();; 
    DECLARE @IndexName VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT IndexName FROM #t) 
    DECLARE @QueryBody VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @xmlEventData.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)')))
    DECLARE @eventType SYSNAME = @xmlEventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','nvarchar(128)');

IF (@eventType IN ('ALTER INDEX', 'CREATE INDEX', 'DROP INDEX'))

BEGIN   

IF (@QueryBody LIKE '%' + @IndexName + '%') AND NOT ((@QueryBody LIKE '%REORG%') OR (@QueryBody LIKE '%REBUILD%')) OR NOT (@QueryBody LIKE '%PAGE_COMPRESSION%')
ROLLBACK;
RAISERROR ('This index is either partitioned, compressed, or both.  Please see the DBAs to update this index', 16, 1) WITH LOG;
RETURN;

END;

ENABLE TRIGGER [dbtrg_PREVENT_COMPRESSED_PARTITION_LOSS_ON_INDEXES] ON ALL SERVER
GO
```

When I try to test it by adding an INCLUDE column to an index and taking the page compression off, I get the following: (Side note: You may ask why I'd do this.  For some unknown reason, this has happened using the GUI in production and we'd like to ensure it can't occur in the future).

```
/*------------------------
USE [AdventureWorks2012]

GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AK_SalesOrderDetail_rowguid] ON [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
(
    [rowguid] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [SalesOrderID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


------------------------*/
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbtrg_PREVENT_COMPRESSED_PARTITION_LOSS_ON_INDEXES, Line 78
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

This, of course, is not the error I specified.  Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: DECLARE @IndexName VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT IndexName FROM #t) pretty sure this select returns multiple rows, which is where the error is coming from. it'll be one of those 4 declares in that section in any case.

Comment: Thank you!  You were absolutely correct about that.

Answer (score 0):

Gareth has it right. `DECLARE @IndexName VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT IndexName FROM #t)` is returning all index names in all databases. I think you want to collect the actual index name being affected using:

schema: `@xmlEventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname')`

name: `@xmlEventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname')`

and then look up the index information in `#t`.

You should also be able to retrieve the database of the event. I would actually consider moving the index name lookup to the beginning of the trigger and then filtering the results in `#t`. You could probably also then drop the cursor since you only need to look up one index in one database.

Answer (score 0):

Gareth was correct about the subquery.  However, the temp table with the cursor in the trigger wouldn't work.  It had to do with SQL Server already having dropped the index before it referenced the temp table itself.  Rearranging the logic was fruitless.  Ultimately, the answer was to create a persisted table that is fed by an Agent job. The table keeps the information that the cursor and temp table originally provided.  The trigger then looks at the table for its condition, and that worked great.  Thank you, everyone, for chipping in (and to my colleague at work, who was invaluable in helping to troubleshoot this really obscure issue).  Here is the code that worked.  I hope it helps anyone else in a similar position:

```
USE [master]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbtrg_PREVENT_COMPRESSED_PARTITION_LOSS_ON_INDEXES] ON ALL SERVER
    AFTER CREATE_INDEX, DROP_INDEX, ALTER_INDEX
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    DECLARE @xmlEventData XML = EVENTDATA();; 
    DECLARE @CurrentIndexName NVARCHAR(100) = ( SELECT
                                                CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @xmlEventData.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)')) ); 
    DECLARE @QueryBody NVARCHAR(MAX) = ( SELECT
                                            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @xmlEventData.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)')) );
    DECLARE @eventType SYSNAME = @xmlEventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'varchar(128)');

       PRINT @eventType 
       PRINT @QueryBody 
       PRINT @CurrentIndexName


               IF EXISTS ( SELECT
                            IndexName
                        FROM
                            dbo.CompressedIndexes
                        WHERE
                            IndexName = @CurrentIndexName )
                AND ( @QueryBody LIKE '%' + @CurrentIndexName + '%' )
                AND NOT ( ( @QueryBody LIKE '%REORG%' )
                          OR ( @QueryBody LIKE '%REBUILD%' )
                        )
                OR NOT ( @QueryBody LIKE '%PAGE_COMPRESSION%' )
                BEGIN
                    RAISERROR ('This index is either partitioned, compressed, or both.  Please see the DBAs to update this index', 16, 1) WITH LOG;
                    ROLLBACK;
                END;
            RETURN;



ENABLE TRIGGER [dbtrg_PREVENT_COMPRESSED_PARTITION_LOSS_ON_INDEXES] ON ALL SERVER;
```

GO